# how do i fix the way my model gets rendered (modeling)

Tags: modeling, rendering

ok so I'm having a problem with the model I'm creating, where it creates these weird lines in the render and edit mode but in solid it looks fine how would I go about fixing this.

solid mode:

[image]

render mode:

[image]

edit mode:

[image]

---

(ps) I was trying to combine object 1 to object 2
object 1:

[image]

object 2:

[image]

if you need more info Lmk in the comments

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: it says uploading but is taking a while any other way? update too big

Comment: or use another platform like wetransfer, send it to yourself and share the link

Comment: would dropbox work? if so heres the dropbox for it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/edvgtxvklqs8wt0/F-100%201970.blend?dl=0

Comment: or here's the wetransfer if dropbox doesn't work:
https://we.tl/t-fnVpemmA5m

Answer (score 2):

You have a split normals problem, click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* in the *Object Data* panel. Also you have inverted normals, recalculate in *Edit* mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: thank you......

Comment: @Jaybracer If this helped you, be sure to upvote. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer :)